# How can my vuex mutation dispatch a new action?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

How can my vuex mutation dispatch a new action or how can my action get read access to the store?

Basically I've got a action that calls an mutation:

```
updateSelectedItems: (context, payload) => {
  context.commit('updateSelectedItems', payload);
},
```

And the mutation that updates the list. It also gets any new items. I need to do something with these new items:

```
updateSelectedItems: (state, payload) => {
  var newItems = _.differenceWith(payload, state.selectedItems, function (a, b) {
    return a.name === b.name;
  });
  state.selectedItems = _.cloneDeep(payload);

  _.each(newItems, (item) => {
    // How do I do this??
    context.dispatch('getItemDetail', item.name)
  });
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not best practice to make your mutations do too much. It's best if they're super-simple and generally do one thing. Let your actions take care of any multi-step processes that might affect the state.

Your example would make more sense structured like this:

```
actions: {
  updateSelectedItems(context, payload) {
    var selectedItems = context.state.selectedItems;
    var newItems = _.differenceWith(payload, selectedItems, (a, b) => {
      return a.name === b.name;
    });

    context.commit('setSelectedItems', payload);

    _.each(newItems, (item) => {
      context.dispatch('getItemDetail', item.name)
    });
  },
  getItemDetail(context, payload) {
    // ...
  }
},
mutations: {
  setSelectedItems(state, payload) {
    state.selectedItems = _.cloneDeep(payload);
  }
}
```

---

If you really need to dispatch something from inside a mutation (which I'd highly recommend *not* doing), you can pass the dispatch function to the mutation as part of the payload.

Comment: This is great. I didnt know the action has read access to the state. Thank you.

Comment: @BeggaBegga: I rejected your edit (context -> {commit,state} ) as it is against the policy to change the code of answers without discussing it with the author. Please comment on the answer and ask the author if he is OK to change it as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible using `this` to call `dispatch` or `commit` (or few others) ... i'm only mentioning this for anybody who comes here and needs it for their specific use case.

In my situation i'm using **fiery-vuex** library which actually passes a function as the payload that will return the updated data, i use this along with a `refresh_time` key in the db to determine when to refresh certain user data

```
SOME_MUTATION( state, getData() ){
    const new_data = getData()
    if( new_data.refresh_time > state.user.refresh_time ){
        this.dispatch( 'refreshFromOtherStateMeta', state.user.id )
    }
    state.user = new_data
}
```